# How to join objects of __NSCFArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am fetching data from Yelp, and I get

```
NSLog(@"categories:%@", categories);
NSLog(@"categories: %@", [categories class]);
NSLog(@"categories: %@", [categories componentsJoinedByString:@","]);
```

I see log as

```
    categories:(
        (
        Thai,
        thai
    )
)
2014-06-19 16:20:47.338 yelp[28929:70b] categories class: __NSCFArray
2014-06-19 16:20:47.341 yelp[28929:70b] categories:(
        (
        Thai,
        thai
    )
)
2014-06-19 16:20:47.341 yelp[28929:70b] categories class: __NSCFArray
2014-06-19 16:20:47.343 yelp[28929:70b] categories:(
        (
        Thai,
        thai
    )
)
2014-06-19 16:20:47.343 yelp[28929:70b] categories class: __NSCFArray
```

so clearly `componentsJoinedByString` is not joining it.

As a newbie, I would like to know how can I join the items of `__NSCFArray`?

Comment: Add one more log: `NSLog(@"categories: %@, categories);`. Update your question with that output.

Comment: looks like `categories` is `@[@[@"Thai", @"thai"]]`

Comment: Based on the updated output you have an array with an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

As per `rmaddy`'s suggestion, I observed what is incorrect.

This works for me

```
NSString *categoriesJoined = [(business[@"categories"][0]) componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```